# Spring Webservices using Apache CXF is not getting deployed in the client server (weblogic)

Tags: spring, web-services, cxf, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c

I am working on building spring webservices for an application. I am using apache cxf for creating webservices and maven for building the war. I am using weblogic 12c to deploy the webservice in my PC. I am using "org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" as the jsonProvider. The code gets deployed in the server running machine without any errors. But when i try to deploy the same code in the client machine that has weblogic 12.2.1 the deployment fails  with the following error:

> "Jersey" failed to preload on startup in Web application:
>   "broker-ws.war".

```
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1490020025257> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "Jersey" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "broker-ws.war".
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
    at weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:98)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:86)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:656)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:600)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1974)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1951)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1841)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2871)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
```

I am not explicitly referencing Jersey anywhere in my project, but i am using jax-rs which is looking for Jersey.The weblogic server in my machine had Jersey jars, but the weblogic present in the client machine did not have Jersey jars. I tried adding the following jars to my **pom.xml**:

```
<!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles/jaxrs-ri -->
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b32</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b32</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-inhabitant-generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-inhabitant-generator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject</artifactId>
            <version>1_2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged/jersey-guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
```

Yet i am unable to deploy the application without any error. I get a different error now.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there
>   is no default generator registered

Please find below my jax-rs configuration in the spring-config file.

```
<jaxrs:server id="restService" address="/rest">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="userService" />
            <ref bean="billingService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
            <bean class="com.brokerws.interceptor.WSLoggingRequestInterceptor" />
        </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
            <bean class="com.brokerws.interceptor.WSLoggingResponseInterceptor" />
        </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

Please find below my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="true" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SuppApp</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>health-check</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.suddenlink.util.HealthCheckServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>health-check</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/healthCheck</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Logback-MDC-Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.suddenlink.traceability.filter.HttpHeaderServletFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>application_name</param-name>
            <param-value>broker-ws</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>application_type</param-name>
            <param-value>ws</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Logback-MDC-Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Can someone tell me what i am missing here.I tried various solutions given over the internet, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: where are the cxf jars included? Do they come with weblogic?

Comment: @yaswanth I have included them in my pom.xml, but i didn't include them in the prefer-application-packages config in the weblogic.xml, so they are coming from weblogic server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the root cause for the issue. It was the spring webapp version, which was making the weblogic server look for jersey dependency. I changed the webapp version from 3.0 to 2.5 and the error is gone. Hope this helps somebody who will run into this issue as this took nearly two days to figure what was actually happening.